# Сделать проверку UIView pointInside UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7

Есть игра с игровым полем:

```
NSInteger width = self.view.bounds.size.width / 6;
UIView* gameDeskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x + width/2,
                                                                (self.view.bounds.size.height-width*5)/2,
                                                                 width * 5, width * 5)];
```

Поле заполнено клетками:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

        x = width * j;
        y = width * lineCount;

        UIView* cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, self.gameDeskView.frame.size.width / 5, self.gameDeskView.frame.size.width / 5)];
        self.cell = cell;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.frame.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] drawInRect:cell.bounds];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
        [gameDeskView addSubview:cell];

        rowCount ++;
    }

    lineCount ++;
}
}
```

И есть цифры, которые я перетаскиваю на поле. 
Мне нужно сделать проверку: если цифра на поле, то  оставляем ее на поле, а если цифра не на поле, то она летит домой:

```
-(void) draggCancel {

if (![ _gameDeskView  pointInside:_view1.center withEvent:nil]) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^ {
                         self.view1.center = CGPointMake(110 , 590);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}else{
}
}
```

И все работает, но почему-то цифра видит координаты поля не те, которые заданы, а как будто поле расположено (`0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width / 6,self.view.bounds.size.width / 6`).

Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для трекинга можно использовать методы:

```
CGRectContainsPoint(someView.frame, draggingView.center)
CGRectContainsRect(someView.frame, draggingView.frame)
CGRectIntersectsRect(someView.frame, draggingView.frame)
```

для транслита координат у UIView есть методы:

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view;
```